# Docker run not working

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

When I use docker compose it performs perfectly the application, however, when I use docker run nothing happens

I have a API Rest (Express & Mongodb) with nginx proxy-pass.

**Docker file:**

```
FROM node:8-alpine

EXPOSE 3000

ARG NODE_ENV
ENV NODE_ENV $NODE_ENV

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
ADD package.json yarn.lock /app/
RUN yarn --pure-lockfile
ADD . /app

CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

**Docker compose:**

```
version: "2"
services:
  api:
    build: .
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=production
    command: yarn start
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    tty: true
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    restart: always

  nginx:
    image: nginx
    depends_on:
      - api
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    restart: always

  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    restart: always
```

Comment: "Not working" isn't really specific enough to make an assessment. You need to get *something* to happen, error or otherwise. Does Docker work on another project? On a different config file?

Comment: It does not start the container, no messages, I check using docker stats and not anything started. Is it that I should use some specific command for this type of application ?

Comment: What are you trying to run with `docker run`

Answer (score 0):

> When I use `docker compose` it performs perfectly the application, however, when I use `docker run` nothing happens

That seems expected, since [`docker run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/) would run *one* image.
As opposed to [`docker compose`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/), which will run a *multi-container* Docker application.

You need for *all* images to run, starting with the right order, in order to anything to happen.